# Some doubts about the use of pathconvert Ant task. What it do?

Tags: java, ant

I am pretty new in Ant (I came from Maven) and I have to execute a refactor of an old Ant script used in an application of my company.

I have some problems to understand what exactly do the followings lines of Ant code:

```
    <pathconvert property="jar.classpath" pathsep=" ">
        <path refid="project.classpath" />
        <chainedmapper>
            <flattenmapper />
            <globmapper from="*" to="lib/*" />
        </chainedmapper>
    </pathconvert>
```

These lines are into a **target** named **jar** that create the **jar** of my application.

Reading on the official Ant documentation I have found that this is an Ant task that:

> Converts nested ResourceCollections, or a reference to just one, into
>   a path form for a particular platform, optionally storing the result
>   into a given property. It can also be used when you need to convert a
>   Resource Collection into a list, separated by a given character, such
>   as a comma or space, or, conversely, e.g. to convert a list of files
>   in a FileList into a path.

This is not clear for me...reading the documentation of **ResourceCollections** is a **set of Resources**

What exactly do this script section? and what is **project.classpath**? (I can't find it into my property file)

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of script is defining the property `jar.classpath`

The value of `jar.classpath` is *computed* as follow:

- it start from the `project.classpath` resource (the project.classpath is probably a classpath container. It means that it contains a set of path element pointing to some jars or directories)
- a `chainedmapper` is applied to the `project.classpath`
- in your sample code the `chainedmapper` is a 2 steps mapper:

step 1: flattenmapper : remove all directory information from the path element. So a path element denoting this file `dir1/dir2/lib1.jar` is transformed to `lib1.jar`

step 2: globmapper : will prefix every path element resulting from step1 with `lib/`. So `lib1.jar` will became `lib/lib1.jar`

As I said: the result of this transformation is stored in `jar.classpath`

This piece of script won't move or copy any file. It is just a *classpath container transformation*. You probably have some other target that will put all required lib in the directory `lib/` so that when `jar.classpath` will be used (probably in a javac task) it will point to existing jar files.

Remark about `project.classpath` : it is probably defined by a `<path id="project.classpath">...</path>` somewhere in your build file. i.e. it is not a property that you will find in a property file.